# magento products are not showing on home page after upgrade from 1.7.2 to 1.9.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I have Upgraded my magento version,followed the following link.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9.
I know php but new to magento

Comment: Have you tried re-indexing and clearing your caches? Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a post upgrade/magento admin issue which belongs over on magento.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Find out how products are inserted to home page. If your site use blocks in CMS page, like this

```
{{block type="xxx/yyyy" name="" template=""}}
```

You should enable usage of block type in

```
System-> Permissions -> Blocks
```

Comment: It worked for me,
Thank you so much.
i had to give the permission to the block